# MaterialButtonToggleGroup force spacing

Tags: android, material-design

I know that MaterialButtonToggleGroup is removing any spacing to keep buttons close to each other but in my case i need to add some spacing between these buttons. 
How can i override this behaviour?

Comment: Have you any clues to share ?

Comment: Nope, i created custom RecyclerView to achieve what i wanted.